# User Defined ClassLoader In C#

Tags: c#

Inspired by this question [why do we need user defined classloader in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550175/why-do-we-need-user-defined-classloader-in-java/3550205#3550205)

Does C# have a way of defining a way to load classes and dlls on demand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle the [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) to manually load assemblies that the runtime cannot locate by itself.

Comment: Hehe, I understood the question wrong then. I was thinking she/he wants to load the class manually (into the heap/memory) :)

Answer (score 1):

.NET offers a lot of options for resolving/configuring assembly/type names while loading. But ultimately, look at [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twt16z2x.aspx) & Assembly.LoadFrom methods - you may even load types from some custom storage using these methods.

Answer (score 0):

No, and why would you want something like that?

The only reason I can think of is for injection/mocking.

For that you would use the .NET profiler API, and rewrite IL on the fly.